# Why are controls missing from Me.Controls()

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Hey guys. I must be missing something. I am trying to cycle throught the lables on my form but it would appear that I am missing quite a few labels... I have a total of 69 lables on my form and I only get 5 hits on the msgbox.  All controls were placed on design time on the  form and not on panels or tabs. Also upon inspecting the me.controls. the count is incorrect as it is missing exactly 64 controls. (The missing lables).

```
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
  If TypeOf ctl Is Label Then
    MsgBox(ctl.Name)
  End If
Next ctl
```

Any ideas why they would not show up?

Brad Swindell

Answer (score 5):

The Controls collection is a heirarchy. You are only getting top level controls. If you want to get all controls then you will need to recursively dig into each child controls Control collection.

> All controls were placed on design
>   time on the form and not on panels or
>   tabs.

Remember that [`GroupBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.aspx) is also a control, with it's own Controls property as well.

This function should give you what you want, but my VB.Net is very, very rusty so if it doesn't compile I apologize.

```
Private Sub PrintAllControlsRecursive(col As Control.ControlCollection, ctrlType As Type)
 If col Is Nothing OrElse col.Count = 0 Then
  Return
 End If

 For Each c As Control In col
  If c.GetType() = ctrlType Then
   MessageBox.Show(c.Name)
  End If

  If c.HasChildren Then
   PrintAllControlsRecursive(c.Controls, ctrlType)
  End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Quote: "not on panels or tabs".  Well, maybe.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub PrintAllControls(ByVal ParentCtl As Control)
        Dim ctl As Control
        MsgBox(ParentCtl.Name + " start", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        For Each ctl In ParentCtl.Controls
            MsgBox(ctl.Name)
            If ctl.HasChildren = True Then
                PrintAllControls(ctl)
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox(ParentCtl.Name + " End", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

## Flatten.

Just use LINQ and a recursive lambda with selectmany to flatten the hierarchy:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

  Dim act As Func(Of Control, IEnumerable(Of Control)) =
    Function(ctl) ctl.Controls.Cast(Of Control)().SelectMany(
      Function(ctl2) ctl2.Controls.Cast(Of Control)().
        Union(act(ctl2))).Union(ctl.Controls.Cast(Of Control))

  MsgBox(Join((From c In act(Me).Distinct Order By c.Name 
        Select c.Name & "--" & c.GetType.ToString).ToArray, vbCrLf))

End Sub
```

Not barnyard programming at all nor chance of repeated items or obscure bugs...

Answer (score -1):

be sure that you're finding controls AFTER the form has been completelly charged, otherwise if you  try to list controls during load process the me.controls.count will be zero.